# Why is $X^2 + Y + 1$ indecomposable?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

We have defined "indecomposable" as follows:

**Definition**: Let $R$ be a commutative ring. We say that $p \in R$ is indecomposable if $p$ is not invertible in $R$ and if the implication $p = a \cdot b \implies a$ or $b$ is invertible, holds for all $a,b \in R$.

**Example**: Let $K[X]$ be the ring of polynomials over the field $K$. Then $aX+b$ with $a,b \in K$ and $a \neq 0$ is indecomposable since:

If $aX + b = P \cdot Q$ with $P, Q \in K[X]$ we have that $deg(aX + b) = 1 = deg(P) + deg(Q)$. So either $P$ or $Q$ is constant and therefore invertible in $K[X]$.

**Question**: How can I apply a similar argument in the case of $K[X,Y]$ and the polynomial $X^2 + Y + 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X^{2}+Y+1=PQ$ with $P,Q\in K\left[X,Y\right]$, then $\deg_{Y}\left(P\right)+\deg_{Y}\left(Q\right)=1$ because $K\left[X\right]$ is an integral domain. Let's say $P$ has degree $1$ in $K\left[X\right]\left[Y\right]$, then $P=RY+S$, with $R,S\in\left[X\right]$. We get $X^{2}+Y+1=RQY+SQ$, so $RQ=1$ and $SQ=X^{2}+1$. In particular $Q$ is invertible.

Comment: Is $deg(X^2+Y+1)$ not 2? And therefore $deg(P) + deg(Q) = 2$?

Comment: I did not use the total degree $\deg$, but the degree $\deg_{Y}$ as a polynomial in $Y$. In this proof, I have implicitly used the isomorphism of $K$-algebras $K\left[X,Y\right]\cong K\left[X\right]\left[Y\right]$.